# About import modules in python

Tags: python, module, python-import

```
import nibabel

nibabel.processing.resample_to_output(input_img, voxel_size)

AttributeError: module 'nibabel' has no attribute 'processing'
```

```
import nibabel
import nibabel.processing

nibabel.processing.resample_to_output(input_img, voxel_size)
```

Why does the first code fail but the second code work?

Comment: Because, as the error states, the module `nibabel` doesn't have a `.processing` attribute. The module `nibabel.processing` exists, but that doesn't mean that it is an attribute on `nibabel`.

Comment: @Crispy13. Do see my answer and let me know if it helps

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @juanpa answer in the comments, you can simply consider these as two different modules.

For this

```
import nibabel
```

You get the error which suggests that this module does not have an attribute named `processing`

But for this

```
import nibabel.processing
```

It works fine since itself can be considered a module and thus means that `processing` is not an attribute of `nibabel`.

So it looks the code that you are trying to run only requires the 2nd import and not the first.